# Batch file throwing error when running .py file: ValueError invalid literal for int()

Tags: python

I am running a .py file that has no issues when running in Jupyter lab. I downloaded that as a .py file and running a batch file to run the program automatically in a scheduler.

```
The batch file reads 

@ECHO OFF 
REM Runs both my project scripts

C:\Anaconda3\python.exe C:\Documents\myfile.py
ECHO Ran myfile

PAUSE
```

When I run the batch file,  it throws me this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '6184.2573'
```

However, the jupyter notebook runs fine with no errors, if there were one, how do I rewrite the batch file to tell me where this error is?

Comment: The error is not from the batch file, it comes from the python script.

Comment: How come when I run the python script i get no errors? Also its from a jupyter notebook, and then saved as a .py file.

Comment: Maybe because it is outside of the jupyter environment.

Comment: Figured out that the issue was the data type in ORACLE, that was causing the issue. I am importing data from Oracle to Python and the issue is there. So I would advise anyone to check their data types if their importing from Oracle and trying to create a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

this is because you are trying inside python file to convert this string `'6184.2573'` to int which is invalid integer so you can either fix the string to valid `integer`  or cast it to `float`

```
print(int('6184.2573'))
```

> output    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:
>   '6184.2573'

```
print(float('6184.2573'))
```

> output 6184.2573

Comment: How do I find this error? The python program runs fine-- no errors.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert a string representing a float to int, that's why the python program is raising that error.

```
>>> x = '6184.2573'
>>> int(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '6184.2573'
```

Try to convert the value in float first and then in int

```
>>> float(x)
6184.2573
>>> int(float(x))
6184
```

Fixing this error in the python program should also fix the problem in the batch.

Comment: However, when I run the python program, I don't get any errors. So I am not sure where it is. Also, I don't have that number written explicitly, so I'm not even sure where it is.

Comment: can you share the file

Comment: Before the cast you can perform a check on the string you are receiving, if the string contains a dot then cast it into float first.

`my_str = '1230.23'`
`my_int = int(float(my_str)) if '.' in my_str else int(my_str)`

It's not clean but it should work

Comment: @ahmedYousif It's too large of a file to share on here.

Comment: @marmar is the error the same after your last change? If yes you may have to check other cast you perform in you program - (I can't comment your answer due to my low reputation)

Comment: @ValerioPreti Yes, still got the same error. I ran through the notebook multiple times, and got no error. When I did find an error, I fixed them, reran it with no errors, updated the batch file, still got the same error

Answer (score 0):

You could try to run your script like this from the batch file:

```
C:\Anaconda3\ipython.exe --pdb C:\Documents\myfile.py
```

It will open a debugger session when you hit the error so that you can check what is going on exactly.